# How do I implement this function so that a word entered into a textbox gets reversed into another one?

Tags: javascript, string, textbox, reverse, palindrome

I'm fairly new with `javascript` and need to know how to take a string in a `textbox` and at the push of a button reverse that string and place it into another `textbox`? Im working on a `palindrome` activity where a word is checked if it is a palindrome then reversed. Here is my code

```
<html>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    function checkPalindrome() {
        var revStr = "";
        var str = document.info.string.value;
        var i = str.length;

        for (var j = i; j >= 0; j--) {
            revStr = revStr + str.charAt(j);
        }
        if (str == revStr) {
            window.alert(str + " is Palindrome");
        } else {
            window.alert(str + " is not a Palindrome");
        }
    }

    function reverseString(parsedString) {
        var str = "";

        for (i = parsedString.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            str += parsedString.substr(i, 1);

        }
        return str;
    }
</script>
</head>

<body bgcolor="#00CC33">
    <center>
        <h1><font color="#FF0099" face="Geneva, Arial, Helvetica,    sans-serif">Palindrome Check</font></h1>
        <form name="info">
            Enter a Word:
            <input type="text" name="string" value="" />
            <br />
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" onClick="checkPalindrome();    reverseString();" />
        </form>
    </center>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I'm confused. Aren't you already reversing the string when you check whether it's a palindrome or not? And wouldn't a palindrome mean that the reversed string is the same as the user-input string? In which case why do you need to re-reverse it?

Answer (score 1):

You can do the reversing with a for loop but there is an easier way.

Convert the string to an array of chars with `string.split('')` and then use the reverse method of array `array.reverse()`.

To compare the reversed and not reversed string you need to convert the normal string to an array too. And then you need to convert both back with `toString()`.
That will create the words with comma separated letters but that's OK for comparison.

Please have a look at the code below and here at [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jgg6stke/).

```js
window.checkPalindrome = function() {
    var str = document.info.string.value,
        strTest = str.split(''),          // creates an array of chars
        revTest = str.split('').reverse(); // create array of chars and reverse array
    
    console.log(strTest.toString(), revTest.toString()); 
    
    if (strTest.toString() == revTest.toString()) { // convert to string for comparison
        alert(str + ' is a Palindrome!');
    } else {
        alert(str + ' is not a Palindrome!');
    }
    
    return false;
};
```

```html
<center>
     <h1><font color="#FF0099" face="Geneva, Arial, Helvetica,    sans-serif">Palindrome Check</font></h1>

    <form name="info">Enter a Word:
        <input type="text" name="string" value="" />
        <br />
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" onClick="return checkPalindrome();" />
    </form>
</center>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like below - It should work
I am assuming that you want to reverse the string only when the string is palindrome. So below code will first check if your string is palindrome or not and if it is then it will reverse that string.

```
 <html>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
        function checkPalindrome() {
            alert(document.getElementById('str'));
            var str=document.getElementById('str').value;
            var len=str.length
            for (i=0; i<Math.floor(len/2);i++)
             {
               if(str[i]!==str[len-i-1])
               {
                 return false;
               }
               else
               {
                 reverseString(str)
               }
             }
        }

        function reverseString(parsedString) {
            var new_reverse='';
            var len=parsedString.length
            for (i=0; i<len;i++)
            {
              new_reverse+=parsedString[len-i-1];
            }
            document.getElementById('revstring').value=new_reverse
        }
    </script>
    </head>

    <body bgcolor="#00CC33">
        <center>
            <h1><font color="#FF0099" face="Geneva, Arial, Helvetica,    sans-serif">Palindrome Check</font></h1>
            <form name="info">
                Enter a Word:
                <input type="text" name="string" id="str" />
                <br/>
                Your Reversed String is :
                <input type="text" id="revstring"/>
                </br>
                <input type="submit" value="Submit" onClick="checkPalindrome();" />
            </form>
        </center>
    </body>

    </html>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
var array  = document.getElementById('str').value.split(""),
newStr = array.reverse().toString().replace(/,/g,""),
output = newStr + " is not a palindrome";
alert( (str != newStr ? output : output.replace("not ","")));
```

Comment: Please elaborate as to **how or why** this solves his problem